# If Location Manager cannot fetch location with GPS_Provider, switch to NETWORK_Provider

Tags: android, geolocation, location, locationmanager, locationlistener

I would like to use GPS_Provider to be my primary method for fetching a Users current location, however, in some cases GPS will not work. If my app can't grab the Users location with GPS, I would like to switch to NETWORK_PROVIDER. How can I implement this?

```
lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

//setting up criteria (biased toward GPS)
Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); 
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
String providerName = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

//requesting location updates (if app cant use GPS, switch to requestLocationUpdates.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
lm.requestLocationUpdates(providerName, 180000, 0, ll);
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to asynchronously request updates for GPS and NETWORK. You would need two separate listeners for both GPS and NETWORK. Whichever listener returns first you would stop getting updates for the other provider. *(i.e if you get a result from the network first, stop getting updates for network AND gps.)*

Let me know if you are confused or not.

Comment: ideally i'd like for GPS to try to fetch the location first for at least 60secs, if it can't get it then switch to network provider. is there a SIMPLE way to implement this?

Comment: That sounds like a horrible user experience. But if that is what you want then you would probably need to use a handler and post a delay of 60 seconds (or 60 seconds in milliseconds).  If you got the location before the 60 seconds is up then remove the handler messages. Otherwise the handler callback will get called. From within the handler callback you could start the network provider.

Answer (score 0):

May or may not be a good idea,

What I did, I registered both Network and GPS providers... Once I start fetching the GPS co ordinates, then I will ingore the co ordinates being fetched network provider using location.getProvider() using a boolean variable.

Answer (score 0):

For my implementation. I first check for the gps location, if it comes back null. Then check for the network location.

```
Location locationGps = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
Location locationNetwork = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (locationGps != null) {
            //set location as gps
            hasFix = true;
        }

        else if (locationNetwork != null) {
            //set location as network
            hasFix = true;
        }
```

Comment: thank you for adding code. I'm new to android/java and have a question about the timing of all of this. does your code first attempt to use gps provider then if it cant, it will use network provider? its my understanding that network provider will almost always provide a faster fix, and if that's the case, locationgps will always be null and the users location will always be determined by locationnetwork right?

Comment: Yes. Sorry the code I pasted isn't very complete, just a snippet used as an example. I first check to see if there is a gps fix, if so - that is what I use as my location. Otherwise if there is a network location I use that - and if neither, I let the user know that the location is not currently available. Its my understanding that the gps fix is more accurate than the network fix. I used this link as a reference http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: this is only checking if theres a last known location fix for either gps or network. I'm looking for checking if GPS is able to get a gps lock (not checking if its enabled by the user).